# spring-nullpointerexception- cant access autowired annotated service (or dao) in a no-annotations class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I have this problem that I cannot fix.

From my `@Controller`, i can easily access my autowired `@Service` class and play with it no problem.
But when I do that from a separate class without annotations, it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

My Controller (works)-

```
@Controller
 public class UserController {
 @Autowired
 UserService userService;...
```

My separate Java class (not working)-

```
public final class UsersManagementUtil {
  @Autowired
  UserService userService;
```

or

```
@Autowired
UserDao userDao;
```

userService or userDao are always null!
Was just trying if any one of them works.

My component scan setting has the root level package set for scanning so that should be OK.

my servlet context -

```
<?xml  version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">
<!-- the application context definition for the
         springapp DispatcherServlet -->
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="x" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager" />

    <!-- package shortended -->
<bean id="messageSource"
class="o.s.c.s.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>

<bean  id="dataSource" 
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

    <!-- package shortened -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="o.s.w.s.v.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <value>0</value>
    </property>
</bean>

      <!-- package shortened -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="o.s.o.h3.a.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>orion.core.models.Question</value>
        <value>orion.core.models.User</value>
        <value>orion.core.models.Space</value>
        <value>orion.core.models.UserSkill</value>
        <value>orion.core.models.Question</value>
        <value>orion.core.models.Rating</value>
    </list>
    </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">

        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager" 
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Any clue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Spring Reference 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-scanning-filters)

> By default, classes annotated with
>   `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`,
>   `@Controller`, or a custom annotation
>   that itself is annotated with
>   `@Component` are the only detected
>   candidate components.

`UsersManagementUtil` should be annotated with one of them based on your need.

Comment: this is what i understood as well but was not working for me.. @Component gets detected but the autowired bean is still null.. no error otherwise

Comment: What about UserService, is that spring managed? (annotated or defined in your xml)

Answer (score 4):

Spring dependency injection works only in components managed by Spring. If your `UsersManagementUtil` is not managed by Spring (i.e. is not a Spring bean), `@Autowired` doesn't work inside it. Either declare it as a Spring bean (using `<bean>` or annotation), or trigger autowiring manually after instantiation of the object using

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(object);
```