# Why is my Spring @Autowired field null?

Tags: java, spring, null, nullpointerexception, autowired

*Note: This is intended to be a canonical answer for a common problem.*

I have a Spring `@Service` class (`MileageFeeCalculator`) that has an `@Autowired` field (`rateService`), but the field is `null` when I try to use it. The logs show that both the `MileageFeeCalculator` bean and the `MileageRateService` bean are being created, but I get a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to call the `mileageCharge` method on my service bean. Why isn't Spring autowiring the field?

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class MileageFeeController {    
    @RequestMapping("/mileage/{miles}")
    @ResponseBody
    public float mileageFee(@PathVariable int miles) {
        MileageFeeCalculator calc = new MileageFeeCalculator();
        return calc.mileageCharge(miles);
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class MileageFeeCalculator {

    @Autowired
    private MileageRateService rateService; // <--- should be autowired, is null

    public float mileageCharge(final int miles) {
        return (miles * rateService.ratePerMile()); // <--- throws NPE
    }
}
```

Service bean that should be autowired in `MileageFeeCalculator` but it isn't:

```
@Service
public class MileageRateService {
    public float ratePerMile() {
        return 0.565f;
    }
}
```

When I try to `GET /mileage/3`, I get this exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.chrylis.example.spring_autowired_npe.MileageFeeCalculator.mileageCharge(MileageFeeCalculator.java:13)
    at com.chrylis.example.spring_autowired_npe.MileageFeeController.mileageFee(MileageFeeController.java:14)
    ...
```

Comment: Another scenario can be when bean `F` is called inside the constructor of another bean `S`. In this case pass the required bean `F` as a parameter to the other beans `S` constructor and annotate the constructor of `S` with `@Autowire`. Remember to annotate the class of the first bean `F` with `@Component`.

Comment: I coded up a few examples very similar to this one using Gradle here: https://github.com/swimorsink/spring-aspectj-examples. Hopefully someone will find it useful.

Answer (score 789, accepted):

The field annotated `@Autowired` is `null` because Spring doesn't know about the copy of `MileageFeeCalculator` that you created with `new` and didn't know to autowire it.

[The Spring Inversion of Control (IoC) container](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) has three main logical components: a registry (called the `ApplicationContext`) of components (beans) that are available to be used by the application, a configurer system that injects objects' dependencies into them by matching up the dependencies with beans in the context, and a dependency solver that can look at a configuration of many different beans and determine how to instantiate and configure them in the necessary order.

The IoC container isn't magic, and it has no way of knowing about Java objects unless you somehow inform it of them. When you call `new`, the JVM instantiates a copy of the new object and hands it straight to you--it never goes through the configuration process. There are three ways that you can get your beans configured.

I have posted all of this code, using Spring Boot to launch, at [this GitHub project](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example); you can look at a full running project for each approach to see everything you need to make it work. **Tag with the `NullPointerException`: [`nonworking`](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example/tree/nonworking)**

### Inject your beans

The most preferable option is to let Spring autowire all of your beans; this requires the least amount of code and is the most maintainable. To make the autowiring work like you wanted, also autowire the `MileageFeeCalculator` like this:

```
@Controller
public class MileageFeeController {

    @Autowired
    private MileageFeeCalculator calc;

    @RequestMapping("/mileage/{miles}")
    @ResponseBody
    public float mileageFee(@PathVariable int miles) {
        return calc.mileageCharge(miles);
    }
}
```

If you need to create a new instance of your service object for different requests, you can still use injection by using [the Spring bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

**Tag that works by injecting the `@MileageFeeCalculator` service object: [`working-inject-bean`](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example/tree/working-inject-bean)**

### Use @Configurable

If you really need objects created with `new` to be autowired, you can [use the Spring `@Configurable` annotation along with AspectJ compile-time weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) to inject your objects. This approach inserts code into your object's constructor that alerts Spring that it's being created so that Spring can configure the new instance. This requires a bit of configuration in your build (such as compiling with `ajc`) and turning on Spring's runtime configuration handlers (`@EnableSpringConfigured` with the JavaConfig syntax). This approach is used by the Roo Active Record system to allow `new` instances of your entities to get the necessary persistence information injected.

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class MileageFeeCalculator {

    @Autowired
    private MileageRateService rateService;

    public float mileageCharge(final int miles) {
        return (miles * rateService.ratePerMile());
    }
}
```

**Tag that works by using `@Configurable` on the service object: [`working-configurable`](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example/tree/working-configurable)**

### Manual bean lookup: not recommended

This approach is suitable only for interfacing with legacy code in special situations. It is nearly always preferable to create a singleton adapter class that Spring can autowire and the legacy code can call, but it is possible to directly ask the Spring application context for a bean.

To do this, you need a class to which Spring can give a reference to the `ApplicationContext` object:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;   
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Then your legacy code can call `getContext()` and retrieve the beans it needs:

```
@Controller
public class MileageFeeController {    
    @RequestMapping("/mileage/{miles}")
    @ResponseBody
    public float mileageFee(@PathVariable int miles) {
        MileageFeeCalculator calc = ApplicationContextHolder.getContext().getBean(MileageFeeCalculator.class);
        return calc.mileageCharge(miles);
    }
}
```

**Tag that works by manually looking up the service object in the Spring context: [`working-manual-lookup`](https://github.com/chrylis/spring_autowired_npe_example/tree/working-manual-lookup)**

Comment: The other thing to look at is making objects for beans in a `@Configuration` bean, where the method to make an instance of a particular bean class is annotated with `@Bean`.

Comment: @DonalFellows I'm not entirely sure what you're talking about ("making" is ambiguous). Are you talking about a problem with multiple calls to `@Bean` methods when using Spring Proxy AOP?

Comment: Hi there, I am running into a similar issue, however when I use your first suggestion, my application thinks "calc" is null when calling the "mileageFee" method. It's as if it never initializes the `@Autowired MileageFeeCalculator calc`. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should add an entry at the top of your answer that explains that retrieving the first bean, the root from which you do everything, should be done through the `ApplicationContext`. Some users (for which I've closed as duplicates) don't understand this.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please explain the issue; I'm not sure exactly what point you're making.

Comment: For non web-app examples (and some times for), if you want to use the bean object tree, you need to access some bean through the `ApplicationContext`. That is the entry point to a Spring application. I've seen questions where users define their XML (or other) configs but fail to define the container. They just expect the an object created through `new` to be managed. When you explain to them that this isn't a bean and they need to get it from the context, they don't understand.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'll munch on that. It's a good point, but this answer is already a bit unwieldy, and it doesn't mention either constructor injection, which avoids this problem entirely, or Spring Boot. I'll try to figure out how to rework it.

Comment: *Spring doesn't know about the copy of MileageFeeCalculator that you created with new and didn't know to autowire it* this sentence solves my problem. Plus one for this.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but specifying both the `@Service` and `@Configurable` annotations on the `MilegageFeeCalculator` might be incorrect, as per the Spring AOP [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable): *...make sure that you **do not use `@Configurable` on bean classes which are registered as regular Spring beans** with the container: You would get double initialization otherwise, once through the container and once through the aspect.* So in essence, you should only pick one of them.

Comment: @PriiduNeemre The problem in this usual case is that the programmer isn't registering the Java object as a Spring bean. Yes, this would be inefficient, but it shouldn't produce incorrect behavior, just suboptimal. I'm meaning to update this to recommend constructor injection anyhow.

Comment: Regarding the "Use @Configurable" solution: I have to use Gradle as the build tool. Is it possbile to incorporate the compile-time weaving somehow into Gradle?

Comment: I had this problem for a few days where Value was null, and my issue was importing the wrong package, even though no errors were thrown...make sure to import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

Comment: Note the last version using ApplicationContextHolder can be simplified by autowiring `BeanFactory` so you can directly call beanFactory.getBean(Service.class);

Answer (score 72):

If you are not coding a web application, make sure your class in which @Autowiring is done is a spring bean. Typically, spring container won't be aware of the class which we might think of as a spring bean. We have to tell the Spring container about our spring classes.

This can be achieved by configuring in appln-contxt or **the better way** is to annotate class as **@Component** and please do not create the annotated class using new operator.
Make sure you get it from Appln-context as below.

```
@Component
public class MyDemo {


    @Autowired
    private MyService  myService; 

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("test");
            ApplicationContext ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
            System.out.println("ctx>>"+ctx);

            Customer c1=null;
            MyDemo myDemo=ctx.getBean(MyDemo.class);
            System.out.println(myDemo);
            myDemo.callService(ctx);


    }

    public void callService(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("---callService---");
        System.out.println(myService);
        myService.callMydao();

    }

}
```

Comment: hi , I gone through your solution, that's correct . And Here I would like to know " Why we don't create instance of annotated class using new operator, may I know the reason behind that.

Comment: if u create the object using new, u will be handling the life cycle of the bean which contradicts the concept of IOC. We need to ask the container to do it, which does it in  a better way

Answer (score 54):

Actually, you should use either JVM managed Objects or Spring-managed Object to invoke methods.
from your above code in your controller class, you are creating a new object to call your service class which has an auto-wired object.

```
MileageFeeCalculator calc = new MileageFeeCalculator();
```

so it won't work that way.

The solution makes this MileageFeeCalculator as an auto-wired object in the Controller itself.

Change your Controller class like below.

```
@Controller
public class MileageFeeController {

    @Autowired
    MileageFeeCalculator calc;  

    @RequestMapping("/mileage/{miles}")
    @ResponseBody
    public float mileageFee(@PathVariable int miles) {
        return calc.mileageCharge(miles);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the answer. Because you're instantiating a new MilageFeeCalculator on your own, Spring isn't involved in the instantiation, so Spring spring has no knowledge the object exists. Thus, it can't do anything to it, like inject dependencies.

Answer (score 36):

I once encountered the same issue when I was *not quite used to the life in the IoC world*. The `@Autowired` field of one of my beans is null at runtime.

The root cause is, instead of using the auto-created bean maintained by the Spring IoC container (whose `@Autowired` field is indeed properly injected), I am `new`ing my own instance of that bean type and using it. Of course this one's `@Autowired` field is null because Spring has no chance to inject it.

Comment: This one helped me forever!

Comment: This works, so long as the `new` object itself is not dependent on IoC

Answer (score 27):

Your problem is new (object creation in java style)

```
MileageFeeCalculator calc = new MileageFeeCalculator();
```

With annotation `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Configuration` beans are created in the
application context of Spring when server is started. But when we create objects
using new operator the object is not registered in  application context which  is already created. For Example Employee.java class i have used.

Check this out:

```java
public class ConfiguredTenantScopedBeanProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        String name = "tenant";
        System.out.println("Bean factory post processor is initialized"); 
        beanFactory.registerScope("employee", new Employee());

        Assert.state(beanFactory instanceof BeanDefinitionRegistry,
                "BeanFactory was not a BeanDefinitionRegistry, so CustomScope cannot be used.");
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;

        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            BeanDefinition definition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
            if (name.equals(definition.getScope())) {
                BeanDefinitionHolder proxyHolder = ScopedProxyUtils.createScopedProxy(new BeanDefinitionHolder(definition, beanName), registry, true);
                registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, proxyHolder.getBeanDefinition());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

*I'm new to Spring, but I discovered this working solution. Please tell me if it's a deprecable way.*

I make Spring inject `applicationContext` in this bean:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SpringUtils {

    public static ApplicationContext ctx;

    /**
     * Make Spring inject the application context
     * and save it on a static variable,
     * so that it can be accessed from any point in the application. 
     */
    @Autowired
    private void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ctx = applicationContext;       
    }
}
```

You can put this code also in the main application class if you want.

Other classes can use it like this:

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean)SpringUtils.ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
```

In this way **any bean can be obtained by any object in the application** (also intantiated with `new`) and **in a static way**.

Comment: This pattern is necessary to make Spring beans accessible to legacy code but should be avoided in new code.

Comment: In my case i required this because there were few third party classes. Spring (IOC) didn't have the control on them. These classes were never called from my spring boot app. I followed this approach and it worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

It seems to be rare case but here is what happened to me:

We used `@Inject` instead of `@Autowired` which is javaee standard supported by Spring. Every places it worked fine and the beans injected correctly, instead of one place. The bean injection seems the same

```
@Inject
Calculator myCalculator
```

At last we found that the error was that we (actually, the Eclipse auto complete feature) imported `com.opensymphony.xwork2.Inject` instead of `javax.inject.Inject` !

So to summarize, make sure that your annotations (`@Autowired`, `@Inject`, `@Service` ,... ) have correct packages!

Answer (score 14):

What hasn't been mentioned here is described in [this](https://technology.amis.nl/2018/02/22/java-how-to-fix-spring-autowired-annotation-not-working-issues/) article in the paragraph "Order of execution".

After "learning" that I had to annotate a class with @Component or the derivatives @Service or @Repository (I guess there are more), to autowire other components inside them, it struck me that these other components still were null inside the constructor of the parent component.

Using @PostConstruct solves that:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    @Autowired MyComponent comp;
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Autowired ComponentDAO dao;

    public MyComponent() {
        // dao is null here
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // dao is initialized here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

**One of the below will work :**

1. The class where you are using @Autowired is not a Bean (You may have used new() somewhere I am sure).
2. Inside the SpringConfig class you have not mentioned the packages the Spring should look for @Component ( I am talking about @ComponentScan(basePackages"here") )

If above two don't work .... start putting System.out.println() and figure out where it is going wrong.

Comment: I used the new() in my code and that caused the problem. I need to use that new(). But also need to use @Autowire in that new Class. How to do that.

Comment: You don't need to do new ! You can simply declare the class variable and use @ Autowire above it. You also have to make sure you have included @ Component above the class (e.g. above class ABC { ... }) which you want to autowire. It will work :)

Answer (score 9):

If this is happening in a test class, make sure you haven't forgotten to annotate the class.

For example, in **Spring Boot**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyTests {
    ....
```

---

### Some time elapses...

Spring Boot [continues to evolve](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4).  It is no longer required to use `@RunWith` *if you use the correct version of JUnit*.

For `@SpringBootTest` to work stand alone, you need to use `@Test` from [JUnit5 instead of JUnit4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48853312).

```
//import org.junit.Test; // JUnit4
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; // JUnit5

@SpringBootTest
public class MyTests {
    ....
```

---

If you get this configuration wrong your tests will compile, but `@Autowired` and `@Value` fields (for example) will be `null`.  Since Spring Boot operates by magic, you may have few avenues for directly debugging this failure.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130486/spring-value-annotation-always-evaluating-as-null

Comment: Note: `@Value` will be null when used with `static` fields.

Comment: Spring provides numerous ways to fail (with no help from the compiler).  When things go wrong, your best bet is to return to square one -- using only the combination of annotations that you know will work together.

Answer (score 9):

In simple words there are mainly two reasons for an `@Autowired` field to be `null`

- **YOUR CLASS IS NOT A  SPRING BEAN.**

The class in which you define the `@Autowire` anotation is not a spring bean. Thus spring will not auto wire the members.

- **THE FIELD IS NOT A BEAN.**

There is no bean with the type or type in hierarchy you specified in the `@Autowired` field is  not yet present in the spring application context or registry

Answer (score 8):

Another solution would be to put a call of
`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)`
to `MileageFeeCalculator` constructor like this:

```
@Service
public class MileageFeeCalculator {

    @Autowired
    private MileageRateService rateService; // <--- will be autowired when constructor is called

    public MileageFeeCalculator() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this)
    }

    public float mileageCharge(final int miles) {
        return (miles * rateService.ratePerMile()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: This uses unsafe publication.

Answer (score 6):

I think you have missed to instruct spring to scan classes with annotation.

You can use `@ComponentScan("packageToScan")` on the configuration class of your spring application to instruct spring to scan.

`@Service, @Component` etc annotations add meta description.

Spring only injects instances of those classes which are either created as bean or marked with annotation.

Classes marked with annotation need to be identified by spring before injecting, `@ComponentScan` instruct spring look for the classes marked with annotation. When Spring finds `@Autowired` it searches for the related bean, and injects the required instance.

Adding annotation only, does not fix or facilitate the dependency injection, Spring needs to know where to look for.

Comment: ran into this when i forgot to add `<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>` to my `beans.xml` file

Answer (score 5):

This is the culprit of giving NullPointerException `MileageFeeCalculator calc = new MileageFeeCalculator();` We are using Spring - don't need to create object manually. Object creation will be taken care of by IoC container.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:** Really smart people were quick to point on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13177782/2583044) answer, which explains the weirdness, described below

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I don't know if it helps anyone, but I was stuck with the same problem even while doing things seemingly right. In my Main method, I have a code like this:

```
ApplicationContext context =
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
        "common.xml",
        "token.xml",
        "pep-config.xml" });
    TokenInitializer ti = context.getBean(TokenInitializer.class);
```

and in a `token.xml` file I've had a line

```
<context:component-scan base-package="package.path"/>
```

I noticed that the package.path does no longer exist, so I've just dropped the line for good.

And after that, NPE started coming in. In a `pep-config.xml` I had just 2 beans:

```
<bean id="someAbac" class="com.pep.SomeAbac" init-method="init"/>
<bean id="settings" class="com.pep.Settings"/>
```

and SomeAbac class has a property declared as

```
@Autowired private Settings settings;
```

for some unknown reason, settings is *null* in init(), when `<context:component-scan/>` element is not present at all, but when it's present and has some bs as a basePackage, everything works well. This line now looks like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="some.shit"/>
```

and it works. May be someone can provide an explanation, but for me it's enough right now )

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13177782/2684760) is the explanation. `<context:component-scan/>` implicitly enables `<context:annotation-config/>` necessary for the `@Autowired` to work.

Answer (score 4):

Also note that if, for whatever reason, you make a method in a `@Service` as `final`, the autowired beans you will access from it will always be `null`.

Comment: I spent a good day banging my head on this issue. Thank you. You're a god. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can also fix this issue using @Service annotation on service class and passing the required bean classA as a parameter to the other beans classB constructor and annotate the constructor of classB with @Autowired. Sample snippet here :

```
@Service
public class ClassB {

    private ClassA classA;

    @Autowired
    public ClassB(ClassA classA) {
        this.classA = classA;
    }

    public void useClassAObjectHere(){
        classA.callMethodOnObjectA();
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked for me bu t can you please elaborate on how this is solving the issue ?

Comment: @CruelEngine, look this is constructor injection (where you explicitly setting an object) instead of just using field injection (this is mostly done by spring configuration mostly). So if you are creating a object of ClassB using "new" operator is some other scope then that would not be visible or autowired set for ClassA. Hence, while calling classB.useClassAObjectHere() would throw NPE as classA object was not autowired if you just declare field Injection. Read chrylis is trying to explain same. And this why constructor injection is recommended over field injection. Does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 1):

This is only valid in case of Unit test.

My Service class had an annotation of service and it was `@autowired` another component class. When I tested the component class was coming null. Because for service class I was creating the object using `new`

If you are writing unit test make sure you are not creating object using `new object()`. Use instead injectMock.

This fixed my issue. Here is a useful [link](https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely related to the question, but if the field injection is null, the constructor based injection will still work fine.

```
    private OrderingClient orderingClient;
    private Sales2Client sales2Client;
    private Settings2Client settings2Client;

    @Autowired
    public BrinkWebTool(OrderingClient orderingClient, Sales2Client sales2Client, Settings2Client settings2Client) {
        this.orderingClient = orderingClient;
        this.sales2Client = sales2Client;
        this.settings2Client = settings2Client;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, don't inject to a `static` member, it will be `null`.

Answer (score -6):

if you are using a `private` method, it will be `null`, try to change `private` to `public` in controller.

Comment: I dont think access modifiers have anything to do here